# Use R to assign individuals based on a different matrix of allocation

Tags: r

Several calculation steps resulted in a data frame as given below

```
FACILITY.ID         LOC0001 LOC0002 LOC0010 LOC0043 LOC0054 LOC0065 LOC0100
       FAC002       1       0       0       1       0       0       0
       FAC003       1       2       0       0       0       0       0
       FAC004       0       0       1       0       0       0       0
       FAC005       0       2       0       0       0       0       0
       FAC006       0       0       0       0       2       0       0
       FAC007       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

The location and facilities are the column and row names respectively.

I have another data frame that looks like below

```
PATIENT.ID   LOCATION.ID
 P001          LOC0002
 P002          LOC0001
 P003          LOC0043
 P004          LOC0001
```

Now, number of patient in the data set and the total of the matrix are the same.

I need to make dataset like

```
PATIENT.ID   FACILITY.ID
 P001          FAC0003
 P002          FAC0002
 P003          FAC0002
 P004          FAC0003
```

Basically, once a patient from a location get a facility, the patient from same location goes to the other facility as per matrix. Cannot do it at all

Comment: I don't understand how you get your output. Can you explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using `data.table`:

```
#create an ID (LOC.NUM) for each empty LOC at each FACILITY
mDT <- melt(capacity, id.vars="FACILITY.ID", variable.name="LOCATION.ID")[
    value > 0L, .(FACILITY.ID=rep(FACILITY.ID, value), LOC.NUM=seq_len(sum(value))), LOCATION.ID]

#perform update join to look up LOCATION for each PATIENT
patients[, LOC.NUM := rowid(LOCATION.ID)][
    mDT, on=.(LOCATION.ID, LOC.NUM), FAC.ID := FACILITY.ID]
```

output:

```
   PATIENT.ID LOCATION.ID LOC.NUM FAC.ID
1:       P001     LOC0002       1 FAC003
2:       P002     LOC0001       1 FAC002
3:       P003     LOC0043       1 FAC002
4:       P004     LOC0001       2 FAC003
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
capacity <- fread("FACILITY.ID         LOC0001 LOC0002 LOC0010 LOC0043 LOC0054 LOC0065 LOC0100
FAC002       1       0       0       1       0       0       0
FAC003       1       2       0       0       0       0       0
FAC004       0       0       1       0       0       0       0
FAC005       0       2       0       0       0       0       0
FAC006       0       0       0       0       2       0       0
FAC007       0       0       0       0       0       0       0")

patients <- fread("PATIENT.ID   LOCATION.ID
P001          LOC0002
P002          LOC0001
P003          LOC0043
P004          LOC0001")
```

Comment: Getting error trying  to run this, cannot find function "." while running 1st code

Comment: Got the results. If . is not working for anyone change it to list